# Job applications not listed in Messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Recent job applications are not listed under `Sent -> Applications` and nor a confirmation email is being sent.

They are listed under `Sent` though.

Maybe a queueing issue or something?

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 10 hours ago we added a check to skip the virus scan if the file had already been scanned, however we added that check too high up the chain and it also was skipping actually sending the application to the employer via email.  We have fixed the bug and all of the applications are queued up now.  They should all be handled in the next hour.